# What is the function of the particle では in this context?

Tags: grammar

This is the context: https://streamable.com/gk3aic

This is the sentence: 私の異常な家族のこと 話したの 友達**では**茗子だけなんだからね

I did not understand the function of this では after the 友達.

Answer (score 1):

It's で + は. This で has the effect of limiting the scope of the topic not unlike in sentences with comparatives or superlatives. You can also say 友達の中では without changing the meaning. She may have talked about her abnormal family with other people, such as teachers, but if the scope is limited to her friends, Meiko is the only one.